# Octave imread support for image IO was disabled

Tags: octave, imread

I am trying to read an image using octave 3.8. I installed octave by downloading code and making it on my system.

I used `imread("oct.png")`

And got this error

> error: imread: invalid image file: imfinfo: support for Image IO was
>   disabled when Octave was built

Please help.

PS I built using the following commands:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
cd octave-3.8.0/
./configure
sudo apt-get install f2c gfortran libblas-dev liblapack-dev libpcre3-dev libreadline-dev
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The latest octave is 3.8.2, not 3.8.0. Have you searched before asking ? [This page](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/error-imread-invalid-image-file-td4647455.html) seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

First: PLease use the stable 3.8.2 tarball, not 3.8.0.

Second: I'm sure the second time you ran ./configure it told you, that the graphicsmagick libs weren't found. Have a look at config.log what's missing.

I can't see which distribution you are using. For Debian GNU/Linux (http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems) you'll have to install

libgraphicsmagick++-dev

Comment: libgraphicsmagick++-dev is installed..
I am trying with 3.8.2 now.. will let you know if I face some problem again :)

Comment: Sam: As I already wrote above, config.log tells you what is missing